# Masking Layer and Mask_Zero in Embedding in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, masking

I have deployed a model where i have a sequence of pages visited by the customer and then the numerical features like time spent on that page etc. Now, to pass the model in keras, I encode the pages information in the form of embeddings and concatenate it with other numerical features and pass it to a LSTM Cell in Keras. Here, to ignore the padded value in embeddings, I am using a mask_zero = True argument in the keras layer and to ignore numerical features for that timestamp, using the masking layer in keras to skip if value = -99 (have used the -99 as the padded value for the numerical feature). Below is the model summary.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Dot, Reshape, Dense, Dropout,Concatenate,Masking

##Input for the Sequential Data
input0 = Input(name=str(inputs[0]),shape=[max_len])
input1 = Input(name=str(inputs[1]),shape=[max_len])
input2 = Input(name=str(inputs[2]),shape=[max_len])
input3 = Input(name=str(inputs[3]),shape=[max_len])
##Input Profiles for the Timespent on each page
input_ts0 = Input(name=str(inputs_ts[0]),shape=[max_len,1])
input_ts1 = Input(name=str(inputs_ts[1]),shape=[max_len,1])
input_ts2 = Input(name=str(inputs_ts[2]),shape=[max_len,1])
input_ts3 = Input(name=str(inputs_ts[3]),shape=[max_len,1])
##Embedding Layer
embed0 = Embedding(def_val+1,50,input_length=max_len,mask_zero=True)(input0)
embed1 = Embedding(def_val+1,50,input_length=max_len,mask_zero=True)(input1)
embed2 = Embedding(def_val+1,50,input_length=max_len,mask_zero=True)(input2)
embed3 = Embedding(def_val+1,50,input_length=max_len,mask_zero=True)(input3)
##concatenate the embedding and time spent on each page
ts_eve_concat0 = Concatenate(name='Concatenated_eve_ts0')([embed0,input_ts0])
ts_eve_concat1 = Concatenate(name='Concatenated_eve_ts1')([embed1,input_ts1])
ts_eve_concat2 = Concatenate(name='Concatenated_eve_ts2')([embed2,input_ts2])
ts_eve_concat3 = Concatenate(name='Concatenated_eve_ts3')([embed3,input_ts3])
##Masking the TS input where there is no information
masking_0 = Masking(mask_value = -99)(ts_eve_concat0)
masking_1 = Masking(mask_value = -99)(ts_eve_concat1)
masking_2 = Masking(mask_value = -99)(ts_eve_concat2)
masking_3 = Masking(mask_value = -99)(ts_eve_concat3)
#LSTM on all the individual layers
lstm0 = LSTM(32)(masking_0)
lstm1 = LSTM(32)(masking_1)
lstm2 = LSTM(32)(masking_2)
lstm3 = LSTM(32)(masking_3)
##Concatenate all the LSTM Layers
concat_lstm = Concatenate(name='Concatenated_lstm')([lstm0,lstm1,lstm2,lstm3])
layer = Dense(64,name='FC1')(concat_lstm)
layer = Activation('relu')(layer)
layer = Dropout(0.3)(layer)
layer = Dense(32,name='FC2',activation='relu')(layer)
layer = Dropout(0.3)(layer)
layer = Dense(1,name='out_layer')(layer)
layer = Activation('sigmoid')(layer)
```

Is this approach correct or do I need to send the information in some other manner

Comment: You don't have to repeat masking in each layer, generally, the mask propagates automatically . Why do you use four Input layers? If your data is a time series, what represents each timeStep?

Comment: I have 4 different sequences. Hence, 4 input layers. To your answer, i have to use masking on embedding layer and then the numerical variables for that timestamp. So embedding layer represents what page someone has clicked on and the other sequence is of the numerical variable like time spent on that page. Not sure that if i mask the embedding layer, will that also work for the numerical features fed as a separate input?

Comment: if you can provide a simple example of your data..